# More efficient way to check if one column equals another?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a piece of code in SQL that checks if all the rows in one column equal another, but my tables are quite large (44 million rows) and it takes upwards of 3 hours to check. I was wondering if there were a way to check it quicker, or to do this in Python?

The code I have as of now:

```
if 'false' in (select IIF(ColA = ColB, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') from database) 

Begin 
"Print ColA != ColB"
END
```

I'm curious if there's a more efficient way of doing this. Originally I had added more after the Begin to insert those rows where they didn't match, but it took even longer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if exists ( select * from database where ColA <> ColB ) begin print "eek" end ?

Comment: What datatype are `ColA` and `ColB`? 3 hours to check 44 million rows is a very long time unless you are comparing BLOB data. I have just run a similar comparison on a table of 81m records (comaring two `INT` columns) which ran more or less instantly

Comment: they are varchar. i also made this code parameterized to check difference schemas in my database, could that have a factor in the time?

Comment: also, i have 40 of these repetitive queries that check the table for various columns, so I don't know if this could also be a factor.

Comment: You are comparing this row by row. Meaning it has to run this comparison for the entire table which is not efficient. But still it shouldn't take anywhere near 3 hours.

Comment: does something like this query run faster? `select top 1 'true' diffAB from yourtable where (ColA != ColB) or (ColA is null and ColB is not null) or (ColA is not null and ColB is null)`

Answer (score 0):

Leave it to the database to optimize such queries. Copying all the data to python will not be faster for sure (plus, I don't think you will be able to write highly optimized python code either).

The obvious optimization to do here is to only return differences, and to stop at the first difference! You want something along the lines of:

```
Select true where cola <> colb limit 1;
```